# compare 4 or more files

Tags: php, javascript, html, diff

Is there a command line utility or a php/py script that will generate a html diff so that multiple files can be compared in order to compare 4 or more files.

Each of my files have max of 10k lines each.

Note: these files are plain text files . not html . Only contain A-Za-z0-9=., . and no HTML tags

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/86905/suggestions-on-how-build-an-html-diff-tool

Comment: the question was to compare 2 html files. I am comparing plain text files here

Comment: good question, but the HTML output is kind of unreadable ? compare 2 files is slightly less confuse, simple way `diff A B > /tmp/diff.a.b; diff A C > /tmp/diff.a.c; diff A D > /tmp/diff.a.d; cat /tmp/diff.a.*;` u can later on beautified it with HTML, not exactly what u want, maybe, just a try-on-error

Answer (score 0):

It depends what type of data you're comparing/analyzing.

The basic solution is

- `file_get_contents` gives you strings of the file data
- `strcmp` will do a "binary-safe compare" of the data

You will probably want to `explode()` your data to delimit it somehow, and compare sections of the data.

Another option is to delimit, loop through, and make a "comparison coefficient" which would indicate to what degree the files deviate from a norm.  For example, File 1 has cc=3, file 4 has cc=8.  File 4 would be a closer match.

A final problem you'll run into is the memory limit on the server computer.  You can change this in `php.ini`.

//EDIT

Just noticed the `diff` tag, but I'll leave this up anyway in case it helps somehow.