# Was DOM Element injected through JS?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, ads

Is it anyhow possible to determine whether an DOM Element was originally in the sourcecode or injected through another js e.g. an adserver?

Watching mutations is not an solution since I'm getting access to the page after the page is rendered.

Comment: I bet there's no way to do that, if you only start observing a completely rendered DOM. The DOM itself doesn't distinguish its nodes by whether one was rendered from HTML or through DOM manipulations.

Comment: The only way I can think of would be to reload the page in another window or in an iframe, and add the MutationObserver on this one. Then you can get the position in DOM and find back which elements do correspond in the original window.

Comment: @Kaiido, listening mutations can I get the source of mutation? So can I see what triggered the mutation?

Comment: @RishatMuhametshin unluckily it really appears to be like that. This is too sad. More and more external scripts are included into pages and noone knows/cares what they do :/ have you never wonderded which script manipulates what?

Comment: @Manuel, no I don't think you can. I'm not a MO specialist and I may be wrong but in my memory you only get the event of the mutation, the target of the event (the one mutated and the appended one in case of a node insertion) and the type of the mutation. Like any event, I don't think there is any info about what part of the code triggered it.

Answer (score 2):

You could send an `XMLHttpRequest` to the same URL to `GET` the original site contents, parse the DOM, remove any scripts you don't like, put it into an offscreen `iframe` so the non-external scripts can run and compare the contents of that `iframe` to current contents.

I made two fiddles to show how this could be done:
[target site](https://jsfiddle.net/clinei/aroy741a/), 
[your JS](https://jsfiddle.net/clinei/dy8xyqgt/)

Comparison of the documents could be done with [isEqualNode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3761669/3027417)

Comment: You should at least compare the result of a `DOMParser` parsing. But setting an attribute on an element through js doesn't mean that you have injected the element.

Comment: Is there any alternative to DOMParser which executes inline js but does not include external js?

Comment: @Manuel `DOMParser` doesn't execute any scripts. You could remove scripts from the parsed DOM based on their `src` attribute and then put the contents in an offscreen `iframe`, let the contents load and then compare __that__

Answer (score 1):

if you what to check the source html you can make a ajax request to the page, get the content and check for differences

Answer (score 0):

If you can save HTML source before any further js actions, than compare new HTML to old one and if they are not equal - element inserted via js.

Comment: "Watching mutations is not an solution since I'm getting access to the page after the page is rendered."

Comment: Even if there wasn't this restriction, `document.body.style.width = '500px'` will change the outerHTML even if you didn't injected the body element through js.