# track and display changes in html

Tags: html

I am looking for a tool to display/track changes in text a little bit like it is done on stackoverflow when a question is edited. Does anybody know of a tool to achieve that?

Comment: You're looking for a diff tool. Specify the language and someone will point one out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to use **diff** for that.

If you can use PHP on your server there's a handy pear package to perform the task you require. Here's an example :

https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-6174867.html

There's actually a actually Javascript implementations outhere as well, not tested though:

http://ejohn.org/projects/javascript-diff-algorithm/

Comment: unfortunately i can't use php.Do you know of any asp.net tool that achieves the same task?

Comment: Did you try the Javascript one ? Really curious about it.

Answer (score 0):

http://aignes.net/

Commercial tool though. I have no idea of a F/OSS alternative.

Answer (score 0):

A copy of my own answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31722/anyone-have-a-diff-algorithm-for-rendered-html/1593296#1593296).

---

What about [DaisyDiff](http://code.google.com/p/daisydiff/) ([Java](http://code.google.com/p/daisydiff/) and [PHP](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Visual_Diff) vesions available).

Following features are really nice:

- Works with badly formed HTML that can be found "in the wild".
- The diffing is more specialized in HTML than XML tree differs. Changing part of a text node will not cause the entire node to be changed.
- In addition to the default visual diff, HTML source can be diffed coherently.
- Provides easy to understand descriptions of the changes.
- The default GUI allows easy browsing of the modifications through keyboard shortcuts and links.