# Is there any Rendered HTML Diff engine for .NET

Tags: .net, html, diff

There are some questions on SO about Html diff engines, but i cant find right answer. What i need is .NET library for comparing two **rendered** html strings and displaying diff (like SO renders questions/answer editing revisions ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/2945808/revisions))).

Comment: SO stores and diffs plain text (formatted using markdown) and not the rendered HTML.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by displaying "rendered" strings: surely you don't mean comparing pixel-by-pixel, so what do you mean? What's the difference between html and rendered html?

Comment: If SO compares plain text than markdown specific characters could be treated as normal text. And this is not right. For example, difference between `**some text**` and `*some text added*` wil be

    *<ins>*</ins>some text <ins>added</ins>*<ins>*</ins>

But should be

    *some text <ins>added</ins>*

Comment: @ChrisW "Rendered HTML" means that i need to compare not html source (like plain text) but rendered murkup. i.e. comparator should be aware of markup-specific characters and skip/process it.

Comment: I still don't know what you mean, by "markup-specific characters". But anyway, maybe a library which does XML-differencing (comparing two XML node-document-trees, instead of comparing two XML serialized-text-files) might be something like what you'd want: so "XML" might be something else to search for, as well as or instead of "HTML".

Comment: Possibly similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061468/html-compare

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/31722/694325 ?

Answer (score 9):

Accepts HTML, outputs HTML:

- [htmldiff.py](https://github.com/cygri/htmldiff) (Python)
- [HTML Diff](https://github.com/Rohland/htmldiff.net) (C#)
- [HTML Diff](http://github.com/myobie/htmldiff) (Ruby)
- [daisydiff](http://code.google.com/p/daisydiff/) (Java)
- [jhtmldiff](http://code.google.com/p/jhtmldiff/) (Java)

Accepts HTML, outputs a data structure:

- [HTML::Diff](http://search.cpan.org/~neilb/HTML-Diff-0.60/lib/HTML/Diff.pm) (Perl)
- [HTML::Differences](http://search.cpan.org/~drolsky/HTML-Differences-0.01/lib/HTML/Differences.pm) (Perl)