# How to use Python to diff two HTML files?

Tags: python, html, diff

I want use Python to diff two HTML files:

Example :

```
html_1 = """
<p>i love it</p>
"""
html_2 = """ 
<h2>i love it </p>
"""
```

the diff file will be like this :

```
diff_html = """
<del><p>i love it</p></dev><ins><h2>i love it</h2></ins>
"""
```

Is there a Python lib to help me do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generate pretty diff html in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1576459/generate-pretty-diff-html-in-python)

Answer (score 13):

[lxml](http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html#html-diff) can do something similar to what you want. From the docs:

```
>>> from lxml.html.diff import htmldiff
>>> doc1 = '''<p>Here is some text.</p>'''
>>> doc2 = '''<p>Here is <b>a lot</b> of <i>text</i>.</p>'''
>>> print htmldiff(doc1, doc2)
<p>Here is <ins><b>a lot</b> of <i>text</i>.</ins> <del>some text.</del> </p>
```

I don't know of any other Python library for this specific task, but you may want to look into word-by-word diffs. They may approximate what you want.

One example is [this one](https://github.com/paulgb/simplediff/blob/master/simplediff.py), implemented in both PHP and Python (save it as `diff.py`, then `import diff`)

```
>>> diff.htmlDiff(a,b)
>>> '<del><p>i</del> <ins><h2>i</ins> love <del>it</p></del> <ins>it </p></ins>'
```

Comment: i have try it , but what i got is `>>> from lxml.html.diff import htmldiff
>>> doc1 = '''<p>Here is some text.</p>'''
>>> doc2 = '''<h2>Here is some text.</h2>'''
>>> print htmldiff(doc1, doc2)
<h2>Here is some text.</h2>
`

Comment: my tag p have changed to chagne h2 , but it didn't show the difference

Comment: the lxml.html.diff docuemnt say: **Markup is generally ignored,** with the markup from new_html
    preserved, and possibly some markup from old_html (though it is
    considered acceptable to lose some of the old markup).  Only the
    words in the HTML are diffed.

Comment: You're right, it works much worse than I remembered. I added an alternative, it's not exactly what you want but may be of help.

Comment: That's nice! If it works for you you should post it as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 2):

I found two Python lib that's helpful:

1. [htmltreediff](https://github.com/christian-oudard/htmltreediff)
2. [htmldiff](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/htmldiff)

However both of it use Python's difflib lib to diff text, while I want to use google's diff.

Answer (score 2):

Checkout [diff2HtmlCompare](https://github.com/wagoodman/diff2HtmlCompare) (full disclosure: I'm the author). If you're trying to just visualize the differences, then this may help you. If you are trying to extract the differences and do something with it, then you can use difflib as suggested by others (the script above just wraps difflib and uses pygments for syntax highlighting). Doug Hellmann has done a pretty good job detailing how to use difflib, I'd suggest checking out [his tutorial](http://pymotw.com/2/difflib/).

Answer (score 1):

You could use `difflib.ndiff()` to look for and replace the "`-`"/"`+`" with your desired HTML.

```
import difflib

html_1 = """
<p>i love it</p>
"""
html_2 = """
<h2>i love it </p>
"""

diff_html = ""
theDiffs = difflib.ndiff(html_1.splitlines(), html_2.splitlines())
for eachDiff in theDiffs:
    if (eachDiff[0] == "-"):
        diff_html += "<del>%s</del>" % eachDiff[1:].strip()
    elif (eachDiff[0] == "+"):
        diff_html += "<ins>%s</ins>" % eachDiff[1:].strip()

print diff_html
```

The result:

```
<del><p>i love it</p></del><ins><h2>i love it </p></ins>
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, python has a build in [difflib](http://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html) that can do this.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what your output is, but the standard library [difflib](http://docs.python.org/library/difflib.html?difflib.HtmlDiff) has a simple htmldiff tool in it, which will build a html diff table for you.

```
import difflib

html_1 = """
<p>i love it</p>
"""
html_2 = """ 
<h2>i love it </p>
"""

htmldiff = difflib.HtmlDiff()
html_table = htmldiff.make_table([html_1], [html_2]) # each item is a list of lines
```