# Building an HTML Diff/Patch Algorithm

Tags: python, html, algorithm, html-parsing, diff

A description of what I'm going to accomplish:

- Input 2 (N is not essential) HTML documents.
- Standardize the HTML format
- Diff the two documents -- external styles are not important but anything inline to the document will be included.
- Determine delta at the HTML Block Element level.

Expanding the last point:

Imagine two pages of the same site that both share a sidebar with what was probably a common ancestor that has been copy/pasted. Each page has some minor changes to the sidebar. The diff will reveal these changes, then I can "walk up" the DOM to find the first common block element shared by them, or just default to `<body>`. In this case, I'd like to walk it up and find that, oh, they share a common `<div id="sidebar">`.

I'm familiar with DaisyDiff and the application is similar -- in the CMS world.

I've also begun playing with the google diff-patch library.

I wanted to give ask this kind of non-specific question to hopefully solicit any advise or guidance that anybody thinks could be helpful. Currently if you put a gun to my head and said "CODE IT" I'd rewrite DaisyDiff in Python and add-in this block-level logic. But I thought maybe there's a better way and the answers to [Anyone have a diff algorithm for rendered HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31722/anyone-have-a-diff-algorithm-for-rendered-html) made me feel warm and fuzzy.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1576459/generate-pretty-diff-html-in-python .

Comment: I'm not sure of your exact application but a DOM ranking algorithm is used by projects like http://www.readability.com/ to extract relevant content. If you want to diff only on the core of the page, something like that might make sense

Comment: Would love to hear an update about this project; if you managed to find what you were looking for and if you plan on open sourcing any of it :)

Comment: Profiled a lot of the libraries here: http://web.onassar.com/blog/2012/11/21/htmldiff-software-discoveries/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you were going to start from scratch, a useful search term would be "tree diff".

There's a pretty awesome blog post [here](http://useless-factor.blogspot.com/2008/01/matching-diffing-and-merging-xml.html), although I just found it by googling "daisydiff python" so I bet you've already seen it. Besides all the interesting theoretical stuff, he mentions the existence of [Logilab's `xmldiff`](http://www.logilab.org/859), an open-source XML differ written in Python. That might be a decent starting point — maybe less correct than trying to wrap or reimplement DaisyDiff, but probably easier to get up and running quickly.

There's also [html-tree-diff](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/html-tree-diff/0.1.2) on pypi, which I found via this Quora link: http://www.quora.com/Is-there-any-good-Python-implementation-of-a-tree-diff-algorithm

There's some theoretical stuff about tree diffing at [efficient diff algorithm for trees and Levenshtein distance](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/10205/efficient-diff-algorithm-for-trees-and-levenshtein-distance) on cstheory.stackexchange.

BTW, just to clarify, you *are* talking about diffing two DOM trees, but not necessarily rendering the diff/merge back into any particular HTML, right? **(EDIT: Right.)** A lot of the similarly-worded questions on here are really asking "how can I color deleted lines red and added lines green" or "how can I make matching paragraphs line up visually", skipping right over the theoretical hard part of "how do I diff two DOM trees in the first place" and the practical hard part of "how do I parse possibly malformed HTML into a DOM tree even before that". :)

Comment: That's correct -- There's a ton of noise in this area about people who want to render a diff in HTML the way you described. I don't care about that, I won't be rendering the diff at all but instead use the output block-element deltas to drive more powerful visualizations of the differences between different pages and versions of the same page. Appreciate your input, this isn't like anything I've built before and I wanted to try to make sure I'm not over thinking it or missing anything obvious.

Answer (score 1):

I know this questions is related to python but you could take a look 3DM - XML 3-way Merging and Differencing Tool (default implementation in java) but here is the actual paper describing the algorithm used http://www.cs.hut.fi/~ctl/3dm/thesis.pdf, and here is the link to the [site](http://tdm.berlios.de/3dm/doc/index.html).

Drawback to this is that you do have to cleanup the document and be able to pars it as XML.

Answer (score 1):

You could start by using [beautifulsoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) to parse both documents.

Then you have a choice:

- use `prettify` to render both documents as more or less standardized HTML and `diff` those.
- compare the [parse trees](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#Navigating%20the%20Parse%20Tree).

The latter allows you to e.g. discard elements that only affect the presentation, not the content. The former is probably easier.