# How to output git diff result side by side with code line numbers to embed in webpage?

Tags: python, html, git, git-diff

I have figured out how to display line numbers and coloured diff using html to embed in email or for a web page, but I am not sure how to go about going for a diff side by side.

Here is my piece of cake to get colour HTML based git diff with line numbers:

```
openTag = """<span style='font-size:1.0em; color: """
openTagEnd = ";font-family: courier, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;'>"
nbsp = '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'

def _traditional_diff(linesfromDiff, openTag, openTagEnd, nbsp):
    lines = []  
    line_num = 0

    def updateLine(line_num, color, line):
        tabs = line.count('\t')
        lines.append("%s:%s#%s%s%s%s</span><br>" % 
        ((repr(line_num), openTag, color, openTagEnd, nbsp*tabs, line)))
        return lines

    for line in linesfromDiff:
        if (line.startswith('diff ') or
                line.startswith('index ') or
                line.startswith('--- ')):
            color = "10EDF5"
            updateLine(line_num, color, line)
            continue

        if line.startswith('-'):
            color = "ff0000"
            updateLine(line_num, color, line)
            continue


        if line.startswith('+++ '):
            color = "07CB14"
            updateLine(line_num, color, line)
            continue

        if line.startswith('@@ '):
            _, old_nr, new_nr, _ = line.split(' ', 3)
            line_num = int(new_nr.split(',')[0])
            color = "5753BE"
            updateLine(line_num, color, line)
            continue

        if line.startswith('+'):
            color = "007900"
            updateLine(line_num, color, line)

        if line.startswith('+') or line.startswith(' '):
            line_num += 1

    return ''.join(lines)
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. thanks.

Comment: is it nowhere in rules to point the reason under post why it is being submitted for close ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get a side-by-side diff when I do "git diff"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7669963/how-can-i-get-a-side-by-side-diff-when-i-do-git-diff)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following process:

- Wrap the openTag in a table column:

  ```
  <td>
  ```
- Replace `nbsp` with an end tag for the column:

  ```
  </td>
  ```
- Put the result of the loop in a table

  ```
  <table><tr>%s</tr></table>
  ```
- Wrap each line in an ol tag
- Each line number would be a li tag

**References**

- [Generate pretty diff html in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1576459/1113772)
- [Character Entity Reference Chart](https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref)

Comment: the line numbers have to match. how would that be taken care then ?