# how to fit the html output from difflib.HtmlDiff in one window without the scroll bar

Tags: python, html, difflib

How to fit the html output from difflib.HtmlDiff in one window without the scroll bar.

I am attaching my html output image in here: [output html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7GCB.png)

Answer (score 3):

For the horizontal scrollbar, you can reduce the width of the table using the optional `wrapcolumn` argument when creating the `difflib.HtmlDiff` object.

```py
html_table = difflib.HtmlDiff(wrapcolumn=80).make_table(
    expected,
    actual,
)
```

If you meant the vertical scrollbar, you can reduce the height by using `context=True` in the `make_table` or `make_file` function call. You can tweak the `numlines` argument too if you want.

`difflib.HtmlDiff` doesn't provide much else for customization, and I've found it very difficult to customize the look using CSS. The HTML it generates is very archaic and inflexible.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html#difflib.HtmlDiff

There are some suggestions for alternatives to `difflib.HtmlDiff` in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1576459/generate-pretty-diff-html-in-python), though.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you can do.

- If the output is in a container like a table or a div you can set the width to 100%
- If the output is in a table you can set the cell width's {.outputDiv table .cell1 width:50px} ....
- You can use css to remove the scrollbar .outputDiv {overflow-x: hidden;}. This will hide all content that won't fit in your outputDiv though so be sure that it is sized correctly