# PHP equivalent to jQuery addClass

Tags: php, string, dom-manipulation

How would you add a class named `newClass` to an **opening** tag like `<a class='abc'>` or `<p style=display:block>` using php?

Comment: For an existing file that you're parsing with PHP, or a file that you're generating using PHP?

Comment: Its generated and only an opening tag.

Comment: So, you're *not* parsing an existing file? Then the usual way is to just write `class="newClass"` where it's supposed to appear... Can you perhaps clarify your situation?

Comment: My function generates a diff between two HTML codes. Modified strings are wrapped by a new span but modified existing elements should get an additional class.

Comment: @Ghommey I would really recommend to use DOM* functionality for this. If you can give a more detailed example, we'll surely can help you better.

Comment: The reason for my function is similar to this so thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31722/anyone-have-a-diff-algorithm-for-rendered-html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Regexp example:

```
<?php
function addClass($htmlString = '', $newClass) {
    $pattern = '/class="([^"]*)"/';

    // class attribute set
    if (preg_match($pattern, $htmlString, $matches)) {
        $definedClasses = explode(' ', $matches[1]);
        if (!in_array($newClass, $definedClasses)) {
            $definedClasses[] = $newClass;
            $htmlString = str_replace($matches[0], sprintf('class="%s"', implode(' ', $definedClasses)), $htmlString);
        }
    }

    // class attribute not set
    else {
        $htmlString = preg_replace('/(\<.+\s)/', sprintf('$1class="%s" ', $newClass), $htmlString);
    }

    return $htmlString;
}

echo addClass('<a class="abc">', 'newClass');
echo addClass('<p style=display:block>', 'newClass');
```

using http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php example

```
<?php
function addClass($node = null, $className) {
    $result = false;

    if (is_string($node)) {
        $dom = DOMDocument::loadXml($node);
        if ($dom instanceof DOMDocument) {
            $definedClasses = explode(' ', $dom->documentElement->getAttribute('class'));
            if (!in_array($className, $definedClasses)) {
                $dom->documentElement->setAttribute(
                    'class', $dom->documentElement->getAttribute('class') . ' ' . $className
                );
            }

            $result = $dom->saveXml($dom->documentElement, true);
        }
    }
    elseif ($node instanceof DOMElement) {
        // this code repetition, could of course be avoided using some more sophisticated structures 
        $definedClasses = explode(' ', $node->getAttribute('class'));
        if (!in_array($className, $definedClasses)) {
            $node->setAttribute('class', $node->getAttribute('class') . ' ' . $className);
        }

        $result = $node;
    }

    return $result;
}

// using a string as input
echo addClass('<a class="abc"></a>', 'newClass');

// using a DOMElement as input
$dom = DOMDocument::loadHtml('<div><a id="something"></a></div>');
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$node = $xpath->query('//*[@id="something"]')->item(0);
if ($node instanceof DOMElement) {
    addClass($node, 'newClass');
    echo $dom->saveXml($node, true);
}
```

I'm purposely not using `loadHTML` (inside the function) to prevent having to dive down into the autogenerated html structure to find the actual given `$htmlString`. This of course implies that `$htmlString` has to be well-formed.

Comment: Good answer, of course if the OP was doing it truly jQuery-esque, the method could be very easily modified to accept a DOMElement object directly, too.

Comment: @rudi_visser You're right. And it would probably a lot more reusable. I'll change it ;)

Comment: Is the closing tag required or does this also work `echo addClass('<a class="abc">', 'newClass');` ?

Comment: It's trying to parse XML so I'd hope not :-) Surely jQuery won't allow you to do that either?

Comment: I guess I have to use regexp then.

Comment: @Ghommey I'm would not recomment that, as your previous comment suggests, you're doing quite a bit of dom manipulation. Maybe you're better of using dom for this to?

Comment: I am using a diff algorithm that returns a string array and I can't change that.

Comment: @Ghommey have a look at the regex example.

Answer (score 2):

[Html class](http://api.nette.org/2.0/Nette.Utils.Html.html) from [Nette Framework](http://nette.org/) does a perfect work for generating HTML tags in PHP.