# I want to apply css class(bootstrap) .img-responsive on all content images

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, wordpress-theming

I am developing a Wordpress theme with the help of bootstrap so I am manually applying cases on all content images like this:

```
<img src="images/logo_03.png" class="img-responsive">
```

Is there any way to apply the same class properties automatically? I don't want to query for this purpose. I am sure bootstrap has a way to solve my problem, so let me know any solution with CSS.

Comment: You can add the class with jQuery, if you want.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add automatic class in image for wordpress post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20473004/how-to-add-automatic-class-in-image-for-wordpress-post)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the LESS mixins directly in your theme.
If you want all images to be responsive you can say:

```
//in your theme.less file
img {
  .img-responsive();
}
```

Will give you this in your `theme.css` file:

```
img {
  //all Bootrap CSS properties that make your image responsive
  //including surrounding media queries
}
```

However, this is not recommended because it applies to all `<img>` tags.

A more professional option would be to make your class like:

```
//in your theme.less file
.theme-img {
  .img-responsive();
  //additional theme-specific styling
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

and apply it to your images:

```
<img class="theme-img" src="..." />
```

Update:
unlike the other answers that suggest using jQuery, this solution doesn't need any scripting and it works in old browsers (eg. IE). Besides it will work for any `<img>` tag that is inserted into the document **even after** the jQuery code is run. If you decide to go with Javascript, however, I recommend using [`document.querySelectAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll) because it doesn't need jQuery and runs slightly faster.

Comment: How to create theme.less file

Comment: If you ask that question, I assume you are using plain CSS to create your theme. That is fine, but as you saw it has its own limitations. LESS is a language that brings more flexibility to CSS. Bootstrap itself is written in LESS and then compiled to CSS. To learn the syntax of LESS, look here: http://lesscss.org All you have to do is to rename your current CSS file to have  ".less" extension. Then @import "bootstrap" from a local directory (where you have downloaded Bootstrap) and then use LESS compiler to generate CSS. OK, it may sound like too much work, but LESS is quite powerful.

Answer (score 4):

Should be easy enough to add the class based on the element attribute, see below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("img").addClass("img-responsive");
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to use the declarations provided by bootstrap for the class `.img-responsive` in your CSS.

For instance, you can set all the images of your website with the content of that class:

```
img {
display: block;
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;}
```

and that's it.

All your images will have the content of the class `.img-responsive` without the need of specify it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add the `img-responsive` class to post thumbnail image in WordPress you can add like this

```
the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail', array('class' => 'img-responsive'));
```

If you want to add to another image in content you can add `img-responsive` class to those image with jQuery just add this to your javascript file

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {

/*add Class to Element*/
 $('.wp-post-image').addClass('"img-responsive');


});
```