# Adding css classes to single images in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, image, class

Is there a way to add css classes or ID's to images in wordpress? Or is there a media library plugin that adds a "css classes" field so you can add a class for that particular image once uploaded?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
function add_image_class($class){
$class .= ' additional-class';
return $class;
}
add_filter('get_image_tag_class','add_image_class');
```

or

```
the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail', array('class' => 'img-responsive'));
```

Hope this will helps you.

For more information,

- [How to add automatic class in image for wordpress post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20473004/how-to-add-automatic-class-in-image-for-wordpress-post)
- [Add CSS class to every image](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/108831/add-css-class-to-every-image)