# Parsing HTML with PHP To Add Class Names

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to figure out a way to add class names to an html output of mine with PHP.

The inputs:

```
<div class="clsA">
  <div>
    <div class="clsB">
      Content (can be anything including clsA, clsB etc.)
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

or

```
<div class="clsC">
  <div class="clsB">
      Content (can be anything including clsC, clsB etc.)
  </div>
</div>
```

and I want the output as

```
<div class="clsA myClass">
  <div>
    <div class="clsB clsInner">
      Content (can be anything including clsA, clsB etc.)
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="clsC myClass">
  <div class="clsB clsInner">
      Content (can be anything including clsC, clsB etc.)
  </div>
</div>
```

For the root class, I want to insert a class name and for a second div with a specified class name, I want to add another class name. But I couldn't figure out a way to add them without using a third party library.

Basically as Pseudo code

```
- Add myClass to the root element
- Add clsInner to the first child element of the root with class name clsB.
```

Note: I can't replace clsB with "clsB clsInner", since there are other classes with clsB inside the content.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I need to do it with PHP.

Comment: Ok, that helps clear things up. Could you provide any examples of what you may have tried thusfar?

Comment: use output buffering and before you finally render the page do some DOM manipulation

Comment: I tried to use DOMDocument but I couldn't be successfull. The HTML is received with output buffering and seeking a way with PHP to modify it.

Comment: Is this some exercise you have to do in class ? Can `<div class="clsC <?= "myClass" ?>">` do the job ?

Comment: @Zyigh Nope :) I graduated like 15 years ago :) Just PHP is not my strong suit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not too familiar with PHP, but would this work?

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$divs = $dom->getElementsByTagName('div');
foreach ($divs as $div) {
        $div->setAttribute('class', $div->getAttribute('class').' myclass');
}
$html = $dom->saveHTML();
```

Comment: Basically as Pseudo code
- Add myClass to the root element
- Add clsInner to the first child element of the root with class name clsB.

Answer (score 1):

As I know, to get an element by class with `DOMDocument`, we need to use also `DOMXpath()`.

So you may try this:

```
<?php
$input = '<div class="clsA">
  <div>
    <div class="clsB">
      Content (can be anything including clsA, clsB etc.)
    </div>
  </div>
</div>';

$dom = new DOMDocument;
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($input);
libxml_use_internal_errors(false);

$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
foreach($xpath->evaluate('//div[contains(@class, "clsA")]') as $clsA) {
    $clsA->setAttribute('class',$clsA->getAttribute('class').' myClass');
}
foreach($xpath->evaluate('//div[contains(@class, "clsB")]') as $clsB) {
    $clsB->setAttribute('class',$clsB->getAttribute('class').' clsInner');
}

echo $dom->saveXML($dom);
?>
```

Comment: Class names were only examples. You could use `//div` and `//div/div` as xpath queries to find parent and child elements.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that I have understood correctly and you wish to modify the DOM after the content has been generated somehow but before the client gets to see it the you can use `output buffering`, `DOMDocument` and `DOMXPath` to fudge around with the content however you see fit before the content is finally rendered. To view the result of the below code you need to look at the source code of the page when you run it ( if you run it "as-is" )

```
<?php

    $outerClassName='myClass';
    $innerClassName='clsInner';

    $attrib='class';

    ob_start();
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Manipulating the output</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="clsA">
          <div>
            <div class="clsB">
              Content (can be anything including clsA, clsB etc.)
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="clsC">
          <div class="clsB">
              Content (can be anything including clsC, clsB etc.)
          </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
<?php
    $dom=new DOMDocument;
    $dom->loadHTML( ob_get_contents() );
    $xp=new DOMXPath( $dom );
    $col = $xp->query( '//div' );



    if( $col->length > 0 ){
        foreach( $col as $node ){

            if( !stristr( $node->getAttribute( $attrib ), $outerClassName ) ) {
                $children=$xp->query( 'div', $node );

                if( $children->length > 0 ){
                    if( $node->hasAttribute( $attrib ) ) $node->setAttribute( $attrib, trim( $node->getAttribute( $attrib ) . ' ' . $outerClassName ) );
                } else {
                    if( $node->hasAttribute( $attrib ) ) $node->setAttribute( $attrib, trim( $node->getAttribute( $attrib ) . ' ' . $innerClassName ) );
                }
            }
        }
        ob_clean();
        echo $dom->saveHTML();
    }


    $dom = $xp = $col = $children = null;
    ob_end_flush();
?>
```